# Why the parameters of this Java class are not working as expected?

Tags: java, android, apk

I extract an xyz.apk file by using Dex2Jar and... I got a email_dex2jar.jar file, but when I see the JAVA classes using jd-gui-0.3.6.windows, the parameters are not as it should be. In place of parameter there is and numeric value. Is there any batter way to get an sourceCode from an apk... ????

Comment: You can not get the exact source code from an apk. When apk file is build, the class and methods are given their own name randomly. You can just analyze the behaviours of classes and methods but can't analyze exact parameters.;-)

Comment: If you need the source code for an APK, you need to ask the author / supplier.  (Welcome to the world of "closed source" ;-) )

Comment: I was searching for that for a long time.... Now my search has been finished successfully :) Any way Thank You guys.... !!!!!! :)